# R: How to use functions in a deep nested list?

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the mean of the variable called `disp` for all *250 dataframes* in my list called: `lst`.

```
for(i in 1:250){
lst[[i]] <- sample_n(mtcars, 25, replace = TRUE)
```

}

I can access `disp` in the first dataframe as `lst[[1]][["disp"]]`, but how can I use sapply to calculate the mean value of `disp` in each of the 250 samples?

Comment: someting like this `sapply(lst,function(x) mean(x$disp))` ?

Answer (score 3):

With `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

     lst%>%
       map("disp")%>%
       map_dbl(mean)

      [1] 254.552 257.404 256.164 214.312 227.660 237.824 221.176 221.648 236.804 232.252 212.948 227.620 242.904
     [14] 271.348 251.412 196.428 207.600 257.244 211.756 220.416 248.980 234.524 275.780 220.720 189.656 230.968
```